# Fastest way to set GPIO in c++ (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, gpio

There is fastest way to set "1" or "0" to a GPIO in c++?

Now, we are using this function:

```
void gpioSet(int gpio, int value)
{
    sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio);
    fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
    sprintf(buf, "%d", value);
    write(fd, buf, 1);
    close(fd);
}
```

Using this function, the CPU takes "time" to set it under C++.

The reason of this question, is that we are using an embedded linux board that have a bug in the SPI. I need to handle the CS (Chip Select) "manually" and this fuction takes time to set or reset the GPIO for the CS.

Thanks.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance (down voters and closers)... What is unclear about this question? He could `memmap` the memory region rather than writing `sysctl` values, and that may be faster or preferred as a best practice.

Comment: I don't understand the two negative votes...

Comment: @Kotik_o I am not a downvoter, but i suspect that it is because this question is broad and you haven't shown your effort to make this program more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of opening and closing the GPIO every time you need to write it, just open it once the first time you need to write it (or at boot time). Then you will skip the expensive operation. (Wrap this functionality in a class to make it clean.)

Also check that you aren't using a buffered write mode when you write to the GPIO.

Comment: Also I'd use `write(fd,value?"1"?"0", 1)` - saves the cost of a printf - but it's the open and the close that will be really expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

BTW pleas see in kernel source this driver drivers/spi/spi-gpio.c. that is easy configure to handle SPI buss on GPIO.